# How to save an image matrix (from opencv) to an xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, opencv

I am new to python, and I would like to save an image matrix (that I obtain from openCV) with dimensions (401, 770, 3) to an xlsx file. Could you suggest a way to do that please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean csv format ?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeess, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: my pleasure and just for saving an answers for other i have submitted in answer section hope you have no issue.

Comment: Oooh at all, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is function available in numpy library you can try it.

```
numpy.savetxt("img_pixels.csv", value, delimiter=',')
```